# How to update QGraphicsScene when item's coordinates change

Tags: c++, qt

I'm making a simple GUI snake game on QT. The head and body parts are just circles with different color (head:red, body:green). Here're some code that I create the initial snake:

```
void MainWindow::initialize() {
    dots = 3; //the initial snake will have 1 head, 2 body parts

    //This is just some random coordinates for the head and body
    for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
         x[z] = 50 - z * STEP;
         y[z] = 50;
    }
    locateSnake();
    timerId = startTimer(DELAY);
}

void MainWindow::locateSnake()
{
    for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
        if (z==0) {
            QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
            QPen redPen(Qt::red);
            head_ = scene_->addEllipse(0, 0, STEP, STEP, redPen, redBrush);
            head_->setPos(x[z],y[z]);
        } else {
            QBrush greenBrush(Qt::green);
            QPen greenPen(Qt::green);
            body_ = scene_->addEllipse(0, 0, STEP, STEP, greenPen, greenBrush);
            body_->setPos(x[z],y[z]);
        }
     }
}
```

When moving the snake, its coordinates also change and I call locateSnake() in the end of moveSnake() function, sth like this:

```
void MainWindow::moveSnake() {
    for (int i = dots; i > 0; i--) {
        x[i] = x[(i - 1)];
        y[i] = y[(i - 1)];
    }

    if (left_) {
        x[0] -= STEP;
    }

    if (right_) {
        x[0] += STEP;
    }

    if (up_) {
        y[0] -= STEP;
    }

    if (down_) {
        y[0] += STEP;
    }
    locateSnake();
}
```

The problem is the program keep adding circles, even not eating the food. I want it somehow retains the number of dots and only change when the snake eats the food.This is what my program runs right now, I only want it to have 3 circles (1 red, 2 green). Any hints?

[image]

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55766179/having-problems-moving-snake-in-qt/55766954#55766954). It should answer to your problem.

Comment: You call `addEllipse()`, but never delete any of the `QGraphicsEllipseItem` objects that `addEllipse()` returns.  That is why you snake keeps growing longer.  In order to limit the length of the snake, you'll need to `delete` the oldest `QGraphicsEllipseItem` just before (or just after) adding the newest one, when your snake has reached its maximum size.  (You could use something like a `std::queue<QGraphicsEllipseItem *>` or a `Queue<QGraphicsEllipseItem *>` to implement a FIFO of pointers for this purpose)

Comment: Also you are adding a whole snake's worth of ellipses at every step, rather than just a single new ellipse; that's probably not what you intended, as it results in a large number of duplicate ellipses located directly on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `body_` from `QGraphicsEllipseItem*` to `QList<QGraphicsEllipseItem*>`.

Then, in your `locateSnake()`:

- as long as `z` is a valid index in your list `body_`, use `->setPos(...)`
- and for `(body_.size() - dots)` add new ellipseItems to the end of `body_`.